# Is there a way to change colour of active tab in finder?

Tags: macbook-pro, big-sur

new  macOS user here. I'm using the dark mode on macOS BigSur 11.5.2. When working with finder tabs, i'm used to thinking the darker tab(or the tab color matching with it's body) is the active one but in my Macbook Pro, the grey tab is the active one. Not sure if it looks the same for everyone or i've accidentally tweaked something that makes it appear this way. Is there a way to make active tab darker and others grey?  See the picture.

[image: Screenshot of finder with 2 tabs]

Here it looks like folder 2 is the active one(for me at-least). But folder 1 is the active folder. Is there a way to make it so that the active tab(folder1) is black instead of grey?

Answer (score 1):

It's always been the case that the lighter tab is the active one.

Compare Light & Dark modes on the same window, Safari & Finder…

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: In light mode it looks fine as the active tab header and body color are white. But in dark mode it is looking very odd since header and body of the tab are different colors. Is there a way to change the colors while staying in the dark mode?

Comment: I very much doubt it. macOS look & feel hasn't really been user-tweakable in a decade.